# Getting input form value and concatenate it

Tags: jquery

I got stuck on this tiny problem: I just can't understand how can I get the values from every input form and concat it. For example, if in one form I will write "Hello" and in another "World", it should return "Hello World" in the div with .results class. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <style>
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <input type=text value=""/>
    <input type=text value=""/>
    <input type=text value=""/>
    <input type=text value=""/>
    <div class="results"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
              $('input').keyup(function() {
              $('.results').html('<b>' + $(this).val() + '</b>');
              });
          });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason you're using 4 inputs for what is ostensibly one value?

Comment: Btw, do you have just multiple inputs, OR multiple forms tag (with multiple inputs)?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by myself, but thanks everyone for help:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('input').keyup(function() {
          $('.results').html("");
          $('input').each(function() {
            $('.results').append($(this).val()+" ");
          });
        });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example with address scenario in forms, i have specified only `input` to filter them only, you can specify select and other different tag as you want, I have separately called it like this `var $inputs = $('#add_location_form :input');` but you can simply use in `filter` function before the `each`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('input').keyup(function() {
  var concat_string = '';
  var $inputs = $('#add_location_form :input');
  $inputs.each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        concat_string += value + ' ';
        $('.results').html('<b>' + concat_string + '</b>');

  });
});
});
```

```css
.formitem {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="add_location.php" name="add_location_form" id="add_location_form">


  <div class="formitem">
    <label for="street">Street Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="street" name="street" />
  </div>

  <div class="formitem">
    <label for="city"> City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
  </div>

  <div class="formitem">
    <label for="zip">Zip:</label>
    <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" />
  </div>




</form>
<div class="results"></div>
```

Comment: But bind uses IDs, which are unique, and I have inputs here. I saw this solution, but I didn't succeed to apply it.

Comment: @AliceJarmusch i have updated the answer check and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

              $('input').keyup(function() {
                   var concat_string = '';
                   $("input").each(function(){
                      var value = $(this).val(); 
                      concat_string+=" "+value ;
                   });
              $('.results').html('<b>' + concat_string + '</b>');
              });
          });
    </script>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2d3Lyaw/)

Comment: I was thinking about that too, but is the each() guaranteed to keep things in order?

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work properly. It returns reference error: val is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var finalResult;
   $('input').keyup(function() {
      $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        finalResult+=$(this).val();
      });
      $('.results').html(finalResult);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but every time when I'm trying to insert something it returns undefined and then doubles the last input. I also had this sort of problem, but I can't find a solution though.